# Jquery Datatable Sorting Issue yyyy-MMMM

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

I'm using Jquery Datatables.
I'm able to generate datatables , but not able to sort date column as date is in the format (yyyy-MMMM).

How can i achieve this can anyone help me please ?

Comment: There are [questions and answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+datatables+date+sort) on Stack Overflow which show how to handle different date formats in DataTables. Have you looked at any of those? What have you tried? Also, take a look at [Ultimate Date-Time Sorting in DataTables](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment).

Comment: If you have not already done so, you can take the [tour] and read [ask].